# Alternatives to Google maps reverse geocoder?

Tags: android, google-maps, reverse-geocoding

I am making an android app which determines the user's location based on his latitude and longitudinal position. So I am using the `Google Maps reverse geocoder`. But the problem is that Google says that one can make only 2500 API calls per day. But I expect my users to be a lot more than 2500. So is there an alternative to `Google Maps reverse geocoder` which lets one make unlimited API calls per day?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number 2500 is per user (I think per IP). If you don't want to do automated queries (which are against the policy) 2500 should be more than enough for a single user.

> "As geocoding limits are per user session, there is no risk that your application will reach a global limit as your userbase grows."
>
> "The 2,500 request limit is per IP address."

from

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat#client

Comment: Can you add a link to your source?

Comment: @vergilcorleone here you go

Comment: Is there any way to pay for unlimited use? Does anyone knows this? Thanks!

Comment: this info is not actual now, there is no info that it limits to 2500

Answer (score 3):

You can use via Google API like insert your longitude and latitude with parameter and send request to the server and server giving the response with address.

```
public static String  getAddressUrl(Context context) {
    String responseText = null;
    // String latitude = "38.89";
    // String longitude  = "-77.03";
    String googleurl = "http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?";
    Log.v(TAG , "Latitude is: " + latitude + "Longitude is:" + longitude);
    StringBuilder sbuilder = new StringBuilder();
    sbuilder.append(googleurl);

    sbuilder.append("q = " + latitude + "," + longitude);
    sbuilder.append("&amp;output = responseText&amp;sensor = true");
    String url = sbuilder.toString();

    Log.v(TAG, "url is: " + url);
    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity httpentity = httpresponse.getEntity();
        InputStream is = httpentity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        responseText = sb.toString();
    }
    catch(ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return responseText;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but Google limits the number of calls to 2500 a day, and I want unlimited calls a day..

Comment: I think no alternative via web service

Comment: @sunil thanks for above code ,i want to ask that Google limits the number of calls to" 2500" a day for a single ip address ,but for android app say for one user ip address is "x.x.x.x" and for another suer ip address is "y.y.y.y" bout are using same application then how "number of calls to" 2500" a day" works ?

Comment: and what is `DefaultHttpClient`??? It's not part of Java or Android SDK

Comment: and url doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 2):

Android's [Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) is my alternative. You should be more specific for convertion of address to long-lat. Here's an [example](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/location/geocoding.html)

Comment: It is dependent on a web service, my question is about alternative web services..

Comment: If it is web service, why did you include android tag?

Comment: I meant that the Android's Geocoder is based on an external web service. My app is for android..

Comment: Theoretically Geocoder is great, but not in practice :/ - tried on my Xperia S --> Service not available meaning GeoCoder is not available on all devices, which makes it, unfortunately, quite useless.